# Assigning variable on each result using foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, variables, foreach

My current code is as follows

```
foreach($flowers as $flower){

        echo "Order by: " . $flower->cust_name . "with item: " . $flower->item;    

        // code result above
        // Order by: Anna Witck with item Lily
        // Order by: George Maxwel with item Rose
        // Order by: Catherine Giin with item Aster
        // and so on..
}
```

But I want it to update it so that **each line result have different (two) variable like as follows.**

```
$anna_cust = $flower->cust_name; // result: Anna Witck
$anna_item = $flower->item; // result: Lily
$george_cust = $flower->cust_name; // result: George Maxwel
$george_item = $flower->item; // result: Rose
$catherine_cust = $flower->cust_name; // result: Catherine Giin
$catherine_item = $flower->item; // result: Aster
```

Comment: What is `$flowers`? An array of `Flower` objects?

Comment: The variable of $flowers is only an array. Thank you!

Comment: I'm so sorry! $flowers is an Object and not an Array.

Answer (score 1):

So if it's an array and not an object, you'd access keys like this:

```
$name = $flower['cust_name'];
```

Comment: I'm sorry! the $flowers is not an Array, but its an Object

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show object data like `->` symbol but $flower is an array so try the following

```
<?php
    foreach($flowers as $flower){
        echo "Order by: " . $flower['cust_name'] . "with item: " .$flower['item'];    
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm so sorry I've updated with new comment of $flowers is an Object, not Array.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$data = array();
foreach ($flowers as $flower) {
    $name = explode(' ', trim($flower->cust_name));

    // Set varibale name
    $var_cust = strtolower($name[0]) . '_cust' ;
    $var_item = strtolower($name[0]) . '_item' ;

    $data[$var_cust] = $flower->cust_name;
    $data[$var_name] = $flower->item;          
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm working with it. Please patient for my feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Using `${}` is a way to create dynamic variables.So Try the following

```
<?php
foreach($flowers as $flower){
        $cast_name = explode(' ', trim($flower->cust_name));
        ${strtolower($cast_name[0]). '_cust'}=$flower->cust_name;
        ${strtolower($cast_name[0]). '_item'}=$flower->item;        
}
?>
```